# Representing MAE and standard deviation for multiple models over multiple bins in python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, boxplot

I have 21 regression models. I am plotting MAE and Standard deviation of models using a errorbar plot in python. However, if I bin the data (say 10 bins), and for each bin now I can calculate MAE, standard deviation for 21 models. Can some one suggest the better type of plot for this type of data. I dont want to create 21 figures, instead a simple figure where I can evaluate performance of all models over different bins.

Comment: Could you give us more details on your research? Why do you have 21 models? How are they similar/different? Why do you need to bin the data? What question you are trying to answer?

Comment: I am working on a regression problem in climate area. There is very poor correlation between the models. I have tried different configurations of ANN,SVM,RF models along with simple linear models. The results are still poor with -ve r2 value. I am seeing how diffferent models have performed over different intervals of target variable range.